# module 'vpython' has no attribute 'ModelComplexity'

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, vpython

[this code is to import vpython](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbKjG.png)

[this code is to find model complexity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wo28a.png)

can anyone help me solve this problem? please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where in the vpython documentation does is say that there exists a ModelComplexity attribute in vpython.

http://www.glowscript.org/docs/VPythonDocs/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question. The term "ModelComplexity" has nothing to do with VPython and does not appear in the documentation for either the visual module or the vpython module. (I did searches of both.)

Bruce

Comment: Oops. I misread John's comment as being the original question. Now I realize the original question was simply confused. Obviously the program that is referenced is simply garbled, attempting to use something that is not part of vpython.